# JPA EntityManagerFactory with Envers is not creating the context

Tags: jpa, hibernate-envers

Please help me in setting up evnvers for my project. Below it my “entityManagerFactory” bean with Envers

Spring-Context.xml

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
      depends-on="flyway">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.example.cns.*" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</prop>
            <!-- <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</prop> -->
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>

            <!-- Listeners for Hibernate Envers -->
            <prop key="hibernate.ejb.event.post-insert">
                org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostInsertEventListener,
                org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.ejb.event.post-update">
                org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostUpdateEventListener,
                org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.ejb.event.post-delete">
                org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostDeleteEventListener,
                org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.ejb.event.pre-collection-update">
                org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.ejb.event.pre-collection-remove">
                org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.ejb.event.post-collection-recreate">
                org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener
            </prop>

            <!-- Properties for Hibernate Envers -->
            <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix">_H</prop>
            <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.revision_field_name">AUDIT_REVISION</prop>
            <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.revision_type_field_name">ACTION_TYPE</prop>
            <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy">org.hibernate.envers.strategy.ValidityAuditStrategy</prop>
            <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy_validity_end_rev_field_name">AUDIT_REVISION_END</prop>
            <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy_validity_store_revend_timestamp">True</prop>
            <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy_validity_revend_timestamp_field_name">AUDIT_REVISION_END_TS</prop>

        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Pom.xml

```xml
<spring.version>3.1.2.RELEASE</spring.version>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1</version> 
</dependency>
```

With above setting I am getting

```
SEVERE: Exception occurred when intialization
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
```

Any help in resolving this is appreciated. Thanks
Mohan

Answer (score 0):

You dont need the envers listeners to be defined for version 4.x

See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html section 15.1

That might simplify your issue.

Answer (score 0):

According the documentation [Joss Docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html#d0e4833)

> Important Unlike in previous versions, you no longer need to specify
>   listeners in the Hibernate configuration file. Just putting the Envers
>   jar on the classpath is enough - listeners will be registered
>   automatically.